# Website not reachable via mobile device

Tags: dns, apache-http-server

I have this very strange problem with a website. The site works normal when coming from a webbrowser which is non-mobile. But when trying to reach the site via a mobile device (tried different browsers) it doesn't get to the website.

The only error I see is:

This website is not available and the message is:

`DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE`

Does anyone know where I should look for the problem. The website is based on Joomla.

The Url of the site is: http://bit.ly/1bOToII

Comment: Maybe something wrong in your DNS entries. Can a CNAME contain `*.xxx.nl`? You result from a `dig www.weisz.nl` points to `www.weisz.nl. 85567 IN CNAME *.weisz.nl.`. None of my sites have the `*.` before the name. Even the site of you provider `pcextreme.nl` does not have this.

Comment: I see your DNS entries are fixed at this moment and all is working correctly now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is down according to **[Down For Everyone Or Just Me](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/)**.

[image]

Comment: But when you try without www it seems to be up....

Comment: the site is not up at weisz.nl/, HTTP request returns a 301 Moved Permanently to http://www.weisz.nl and browser is  unable to resolve host address “www.weisz.nl”.ie,host is down.

Comment: Are you trying from a mobile device or from a pc?

Comment: from linux terminal.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/arrk9yjn7/